systemd-networkd static leases in DHCPServer for ve
I would like to assign some predefined IP addresses (or addresses from a predefined pool) for virtual ethernets created for systemd-nspawn'ed VMs.
Can someone give a hint, how this could be achieved?
What I have tried so far:

configuration by default (by /lib/systemd/network/80-container-ve.network in fact)

Each VM receives an address in a /28 randomly chosen network (due to Address=0.0.0.0/28 statement). Well, it works, and the services inside the VM are visible to an outer network (not just host node), given a custom route line is manually added to each host accessing those services. However those addresses can not be predicted, and each created VM needs a dedicated route line in a router or hosts accessing VM's services. Quite a cumbersome and boring solution.

Fixed address for each ve-* created.

The routing table of the host node becomes invalid, because of extra entries for each created VE interface. If I manually delete those entries from the host routing table, then the network on the host node is restored. Again, the solution looks broken.

Adding static leases via [DHCPServerStaticLease]:

[Match]
Kind=veth
Name=ve-*

[Network]
# Default to using a /28 prefix, giving up to 13 addresses per container.
Address=0.0.0.0/28        
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
DHCPServer=yes
IPMasquerade=both
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=customer-bridge
IPv6AcceptRA=no
IPv6SendRA=yes

[DHCPServerStaticLease]
# MAC address of the VM inner interface (host0@if*)
MACAddress=be:5e:56:66:75:16
Address=192.168.223.226

Well, it seems that those leases are ignored.

Changing Address=0.0.0.0/28 to some fixed range

e.g. Address=192.168.223.224/28
got the following in the logs:
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/80-container-ve.network.
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Link UP
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Gained carrier
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Failed to configure address pool for DHCPv4 server instance: Numerical result out of range
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Failed to configure DHCP server: Numerical result out of range
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Failed
Nov 05 16:52:27 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Trying to reconfigure the interface.
Nov 05 16:52:29 gorgy systemd-networkd[257024]: ve-perft3: Gained IPv6LL

Still no success.
So the question is how to do it properly.

The "usable" addresses within the 192.168.223.224/28 subnet are 192.168.223.225 - 192.168.223.238, and that's an Address= field (that expects a usable address, with a prefix length that indicates the subnet size).

By the way, it's probably quite expected that #3 "doesn't work". I doubt that there is code to make sure that the 0.0.0.0/N magic would try to choose a range according to the static leases. And when the range is going to be random, the static leases are very unlikely to fit by chance.

A small note: A /28 network contains 16 addresses total and 13 "usable" addresses (-1 for "nework", -1 for host "gateway", -1 for broadcast). Anyway, the range could be increased (e.g. by using /27), however it doesn't solve the problem.

Yes, it looks like that the most "natural" (well, at least, natural for me :) ) way is unsupported in the code. Probably I have to switch to using bridges and all that stuff.

"Gateway address" does not count as an unusable address because "gateway" is a host too (at least broadly speaking). Like for example your nspawn host would be the (default) "gateway" of your nspawn containers. (Besides, unlike the subnet ID and the broadcast address, "gateway address" does not have to be a specific address within the range. Technically any host/IP in the subnet can be the default gateway, and not even all hosts in the subnet have to use the same host as their default gateway.)

(With that said, I don't know if systemd is smart enough to subtract only the "dhcp server address", which by default would be the "gateway address", if it is not the first usable address (192.168.223.225 in the case above). I mean like I wonder if it would also remove all the addresses before the server address from the pool it will use, if the server address is e.g. in the middle of the subnet (usable) range.)

systemd-networkd in veth mode assigns one address to the host network interface specific to the VM (e.g. ve-smth@ifN) thus leaving 13 addresses of a /28 network for the ifaces within the VM. Anyway, the network is chosen randomly "from an unused range" which is not convenient.

There's no such thing as "veth mode". Address= takes a usable (as per my / the actual definition) address, not a subnet ID. It "allocates" a subnet when you use the 0.0.0.0 special value, which means it will pick a subnet according to the current situation/configuration of the system and from the picked subnet it configures one of the usable IP addresses on the interface (not sure if it would always be the first one), but that does NOT mean that if you want a specific subnet (#4), you should set the subnet ID as the value for the field.

(In other words, try Address=192.168.223.225/28 instead of Address=Address=192.168.223.224/28, as the latter is at least "unorthodox" as per the documentation of Address=, if not completely unexpected as in it does not undocumented hack to handle such invalid value. And with the former 192.168.223.225 will be used as the DHCP server address and gateway address emit/advertised by the DHCP server to the clients/nspawns, unless you further configure it to do otherwise.)

Btw, if you want to use specific subnet(s) for multiple pairs of veths (like if you need multiple nspawns; but really even if just one), you should probably create/manage/configure the veth pairs yourself instead of letting the nspawns (and the default configure file mentioned above) do it for you. There's the --network-interface / Interface= option that allows you to use a precreated / customized veth for each of your nspawn. (Just make sure you don't name them ve-*.) See systemd.netdev for further details.

Ok, thank you, I will try to do it manually
